# Show Notification data when "Hide sensitive information" is active

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

In Android, if a user has lock screen and has selected hide sensitive information option, the notification's description shows as "content-hidden" while the screen is locked. I understand that this is how the feature is designed but is there a way for the notification of my app to be displayed as normal notification in this case too?

My app is solely based on Notifications so I want to give user a change to always see the notifications, if he wishes. I tried searching for a way to always show notification text but couldn't find any.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [Notifications guide on visibility](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#lockscreenNotification) notes that you can use [setVisibility()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setVisibility(int)) with [VISIBILITY_PUBLIC](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.html#VISIBILITY_PUBLIC) to always allow users to view your notification, even when they have "Hide sensitive information" enabled.

You can also use [setPublicVersion()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setPublicVersion(android.app.Notification)) to build a separate notification that shows only non-sensitive information to specifically handle this case.